# Ping to my own public IP results in host unreachable

Tags: networking, ip

First of all, I'm running a Manjaro 3.10 (Archlinux x64) install.

I'm trying to make my No-IP configuration work. I have tried to ping my no-ip host and I recieve `host unreachable` ICMPs only. I was wondering if was a noip problem, so I have checked out my public ip with:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

I have taken the result public Ip and done a ping to it:

```
ping my_public_ip
```

The result was `host unreachable` responses too, so I suppose no-ip has nothing to do with this situation (But I'm not sure, thats why I commented it on the question).

Could be a double IP problem. I have a RapsberryPI (With archlinux too) and I have noticed that it has exactly the same public IP.

**Whats wrong in my setup? Is this a IP conflict problem? If could be a problem, what I can do to check it?**

Comment: How are your computers connected to the internet? Directly via modems or behind the same router?

Comment: @cpugeniousmv behind the same router

Comment: Try disconnecting one of the two devices you suspect of having duplicate IPs maybe?

Comment: What are the IP addresses involved? In particular, we need to know which ones are local and which ones are not — see [Special-use IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address#Special-use_addresses). Also please clarify your network topology (what is connected to what, and which of these is doing routing, NAT, …).

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably pinging an IP address that doesn't belong to your local host at all. In the age of IP masquerading (aka NAT), the fact that you're communication on the internet is seen as coming from a specific address doesn't mean that address is assigned to your computer.

Use the following command (or any alternative) to check your ip configuration:

```
ip address
```

You can typically ping IP addresses that you see in the output of this commend directly (using the loopback interface internally). But there's nothing that would guarantee you can ping an address that belongs to some router on the way to other internet hosts.

Answer (score 1):

All the devices connected to your router will have same public IP because one external/public IP is given by your ISP for each internet connection and that one public IP is with your router. I know I'm being contradictory here but let me explain it further.

Your isp just gave you one connection/public IP but you use internet on multiple devices. Router is doing that job to ditch your ISP and splitting your single connection in multiple devices and this is done by NAT(Network Address Translation).
When you ping(specifically) your public IP generally the router gives response to such requests.

There are two reasons that you didn't got any response.

1.Ping is blocked on your router.

2.Router is incapable of responding to ping(old router)

If second is your case then you have to go for port forwarding.
Port forwarding is required on your router when you want an public PC to access your PC on specific port.
eg. you want to run an http server(port 80) on your RPi.

Assume a case where I type your ddns on my browser. Even if you have installed a http server running on your system, I won't get any response because that request will be dropped by your router.
Why so?
Because you haven't told your router that on which PC this request(http-request here) has to be send if it gets it(like on you pc or on your RPi). And that problem is solved by port forwarding. You can see your router website if want to know how to configure port forwarding.